# Angular/ dependency injection outside constructor

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection, angular5

I have a class

```
export class MyClass {

   constructor(data: any) {
     this.data = data;
  }
}
```

I also want to inject ChangeDetectorRef like this.  `constructor(data: any, cd: ChangeDetectorRef )`

But in this case I can't create object from MyClass like this `const myClass = new MyClass(data)`
Is it possible to inject ChangeDetectorRef outside constructor?

Answer (score 0):

Just make `ChangeDetectorRef` as optional parameter of constructor

```
export class MyClass {
   constructor(data: any, cd?: ChangeDetectorRef ) {
     this.data = data;
  }
}
```

And call it like `const myClass = new MyClass(data)`

EDIT :

If you want to use the ChangeDetectorRef in service then pass it is as an argument from the component

```
export class MyComponent{
    constructor(cd : ChangeDetectorRef ){
       const myClass = new MyClass(data, cd);
    }
}
```

Comment: this is not a solution because after that value of this.cd will be undefined

Comment: @VahanHarutyunyan If you want to utilize `cd`, then you have to pass it from component or wherever you call it from. For this you need to have `ChangeDetectionRef` injected within the caller class

Answer (score 0):

You can go through a setter :

```
export class MyClass {
   cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef;
   constructor(data: any) {
     this.data = data;
   }

   setCdRef(value: ChangeDetectorRef) { this.cdRef = value; }
}
```

Comment: But how setCdRef should be called?

Comment: Through your object, with this : `const myClass = new MyClass(data); myClass.setCdRef(this.cdRef)`. You will create an instance of your class into a component, and this component shoud have a cdRef in it. Or maybe you could use the injector, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You could also have a setter method that you'd need to call after once you've got the correct reference.

```
export class MyClass 
{
    private cd: ChangeDetectorRef;
    constructor(data: any ) {
    this.data = data;
    }

    setChangeDetector(cd: ChangeDetectorRef )
    {
       this.cd = cd;
    }
}
```

**Other options**

This is **not** dependency injection, but you could also assign a global reference to the `ChangeDetectorRef` when your main module is initialised

**module.ts**

```
 import {ChangeDetectorRef} from '@angular/core';

  export let CDInstance: ChangeDetectorRef;

  export class AppModule
  {
    constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef)
    {
      CDInstance = this.cd;
    }
  }
```

**myclass.ts**

```
import {InjectorInstance} from './app.module';

export class MyClass
{

  private cd: ChangeDetectorRef;

  constructor(data: any)
  {
    this.data = data;
    this.cd = CDInstance;
  }
}
```